# replacement for npm package request

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

So, I am trying to upgrade a repo from a 3rd party project that is no longer maintained. The issue is it uses "request". Here is a sample of the code

To be clear... The package is called "REQUEST"

```
request.post(
                    {
                        url: config.URL,
                        form: {
                            a: "checkToken",
                            webmasterid: sited,
                            token: token,
                        },
                    },
```

As I am not a expressJS/Socket.io guy, I am not sure what the new format would be and what I would do to fix this. There are 48 different instances of request.post so I can only guess there is a solution.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I FINALLY found an article that gave me the ability to choose based on what is needed. As I am only doing a simple post I could have done this a number of ways but I settled on GOT just so I know I am working on the right solution with something that is full featured.

https://nodesource.com/blog/express-going-into-maintenance-mode

I hope this helps someone else